# How can I create a program to accept ten numbers from a user?

Tags: ruby, syntax-error

I am creating a program that accepts ten numbers from a user. Then, it displays the total of the ten numbers, their average, and the smallest and largest numbers. Finally, it is supposed to display the word 'Jackpot!' for every number entered that is of the same or greater value than 100, and 'Tough Luck.' for every number less than 100.

My code does not seem to be working and will not run in Ruby.

```
puts 'Please enter 10 numbers one at a time.' 
num1=gets.chomp
num2=gets.chomp
num3=gets.chomp
num4=gets.chomp
num5=gets.chomp
num6=gets.chomp 
num7=gets.chomp
num8=gets.chomp
num9=gets.chomp
num10=gets.chomp
value_list=[num1, num2, num3, num4, num5, num6, num7, num8, num9, num10] 
subtotal=0
for x in 0..9
subtotal=subtotal+value_list[x]
puts 'Total: ' + subtotal
average=subtotal/10.to_f
average=sprintf("%.2f",average)
puts 'Average: ' + average
puts 'Smallest value: ' + sprintf("%.2f",value_list.min.to_s)
puts 'Largest value: ' + sprintf("%.2f",value_list.min.to_s)
if num1..num10 >=100
puts 'Jackpot!'
else
puts 'Tough Luck.'
sleep 120
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things:

1. You need to `end` your blocks: `for ... end`, `if ... else ... end`, etc. This is the main reason it won't run, i.e. the parser doesn't recognize it as valid syntax.
2. `gets.chomp` returns a string, but you are looking for integers. Try `gets.chomp.to_i` to force integer types.
3. `'Total: ' + subtotal`: you would be adding an integer to a string, which is not allowed. Ruby string interpolation goes like this (double quotes required): `"Total: #{subtotal}"`. This will transform the `subtotal` variable into a string and insert it into the other string on the fly.
4. I'm not sure what you're trying to do here: `if num1..num10 >= 100`. Is this if any member of the range is greater than 100, or if the sum is greater than 100?

There's also a lot of optimization you can do here. One good opportunity is when you have a lot of repeated code, as in `num1 = gets.chomp.to_i; num2 = gets ... etc`.

Here's a version of your program that (I think) does what you want it to. If you're serious about learning Ruby, go look up the documentation for some of these methods (`<<`, `inject`, `.times` etc):

```
puts 'Please enter 10 numbers one at a time.' 
value_list = []
10.times do
  value_list << gets.chomp.to_i
end

subtotal = value_list.inject(:+)

puts "Total: #{subtotal}"
puts "Average: #{(subtotal/10.0).round(2)}"
puts "Smallest value: #{value_list.min}"
puts "Largest value: #{value_list.max}" 

if subtotal >= 100
  puts 'Jackpot!'
else
  puts 'Tough Luck.'
end
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: `gets.chomp.to_i` isn't needed, `gets.to_i` is sufficient. `"1\n".to_i
=> 1`

Comment: Nice, didn't know about that one.

Answer (score 0):

Your code need some `end` statements, and you need to convert the input to numbers before calculation.
You also need to close the `for` at the end and the `if` before the `'Jackpot!'`.

You can convert all of the strings input using `map`:

```
value_list = value_list.map(&:to_i)
```

Where you calculate the subtotal you need to covert its data to a string, or just interpolate the data:

```
puts "Total: #{subtotal}"
```

After this you need to redo `if num1..num10 >=100`. It compares `100` to a Range which is wrong.